# Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS hangs on boot after latest dist-upgrade in VMware

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, vmware

I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` as follows:

```
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-51 linux-headers-3.19.0-51-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic-lts-vivid linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid
  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid
3 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 65.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 288 MB of additional disk space will be used.

Setting up linux-image-generic-lts-vivid (3.19.0.51.36) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.19.0-51 (3.19.0-51.57~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.19.0-51-generic (3.19.0-51.57~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid (3.19.0.51.36) ...
Setting up linux-generic-lts-vivid (3.19.0.51.36) ...
```

After this, Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64 LTS doesn't boot correctly and hangs on this screen:

[image]

This happens on all VMs I'm trying. I can reproduce it by creating / reverting snapshots.

Update:
This is the content of `/var/log/boot.log` after booting with the previous kernel via advanced boot options in GRUB:

```
 * Stopping Read required files in advance                               [ OK ]
 * Starting Mount filesystems on boot                                    [ OK ]
 * Starting Populate /dev filesystem                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting Populate and link to /run filesystem                         [ OK ]
 * Stopping Populate /dev filesystem                                     [ OK ]
 * Stopping Populate and link to /run filesystem                         [ OK ]
 * Stopping Track if upstart is running in a container                   [ OK ]
 * Starting Initialize or finalize resolvconf                            [ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that the rootfs is mounted                   [ OK ]
 * Starting mount available cgroup filesystems                           [ OK ]
 * Starting set console keymap                                           [ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted         [ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted         [ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge udev events into upstart                              [ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that remote filesystems are mounted          [ OK ]
 * Stopping set console keymap                                           [ OK ]
 * Starting Clean /tmp directory                                         [ OK ]
 * Stopping Clean /tmp directory                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that local filesystems are mounted           [ OK ]
 * Starting device node and kernel event manager                         [ OK ]
 * Starting D-Bus system message bus                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting flush early job output to logs                               [ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount filesystems on boot                                    [ OK ]
 * Stopping flush early job output to logs                               [ OK ]
 * Starting load modules from /etc/modules                               [ OK ]
 * Starting cold plug devices                                            [ OK ]
 * Starting log initial device creation                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting SystemD login management service                             [ OK ]
 * Stopping load modules from /etc/modules                               [ OK ]
 * Starting system logging daemon                                        [ OK ]
 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon                                           [ OK ]
 * Starting bluetooth daemon                                             [ OK ]
 * Starting Reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure remote q[ OK ]are populated
 * Stopping Reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure remote q[ OK ]are populated
 * Starting Bridge file events into upstart                              [ OK ]
 * Starting Uncomplicated firewall                                       [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Starting Failsafe Boot Delay                                          [ OK ]
 * Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay                                          [ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Starting System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Starting modem connection manager                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting userspace bootsplash                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting network connection manager                                   [ OK ]
 * Stopping userspace bootsplash                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
 * Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge socket events into upstart                            [ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting AppArmor profiles                                                                [ OK ]
 * Setting up X socket directories...                                                        [ OK ]
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility                              [ OK ]
 * Starting Restore Sound Card State                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon                 [ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon                              [ OK ]
 * Starting Restore Sound Card State                                     [fail]
 * Starting crash report submission daemon                               [ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron                                         [ OK ]
 * Stopping Restore Sound Card State                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation                            [ OK ]
 * Starting cups-browsed - Bonjour remote printer browsing daemon        [ OK ]
 * Starting configure virtual network devices                            [ OK ]
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules * Stopping cold plug devices          [ OK ]
 * Stopping log initial device creation                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting save udev log and update rules                               [ OK ]
 * Stopping save udev log and update rules                               [ OK ]
 ...done.
```

Comment: You most likely noticed this line: `Starting Restore Sound Card State` as you are using a VM for Ubuntu, try disabling the virtual sound interface and restart. Most likely the kernel upgrade above broke the driver for them.

Comment: This happened before the update already. But I disabled it anyway now. Didn't fix it.

Comment: Hmm you could try using the latest kernel from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/ to see if that works. Without proper kernel logs I cannot say what might be causing the issue (`cat /var/log/kern.log`). Maybe also look into the zipped kernel logs within the folder.

Comment: @Flatron I created a pastebin containing the kern.log for the time in question: http://pastebin.com/iYDjfcxU

Comment: There was a security update yesterday, and I suspect that [bug #1548985](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1548985) has something to do with it.

Comment: I am also having the same issue in a vm, pressed escape and choose the older version and it worked

Comment: Filed a bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1550090

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At Ubuntu Forums there's at least one thread showing that my issue is caused by the latest Ubuntu Kernel Update (linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2314723

**Update:**

@alexmurray filed a bug (which has been already confirmed) at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1550090

Please vote over there if you're affected (please don't create "me too" answers here).

**Update:**

[Fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/linux/+bug/1548587) by `3.19.0-51.58~14.04.1`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and reverted back to the older kernel.

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot up and select advanced options, then select an older kernel (Pay attention to what the latest kernel is). This will allow you to go into the Ubuntu desktop.
2. From there open up synaptic package manager. Locate `linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic` (or the latest kernel you have installed).
3. Right-click and select "Mark for Removal".
4. Apply and restart.

Comment: Same problem, with exactly the same kernel version.  Running on a VM inside of VMWare Workstation.  This solution resolved it.

Comment: Those affected by this bug should mark it as affecting them on Launchpad.   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1550090

Answer (score 0):

I haven't kept a record of the boot text information, but had similar problems (Windows 7 64-bit host VMware Workstation 12 Player), initially with the 15.10 Wily Werewolf VM I had been using for a while. After installing the latest updates a couple of days ago my VM wouldn't boot and got stuck on a black screen. I tried to work around the problem by creating a new 14.04.3 LTS VM from the .iso I had used before. This guest VM worked fine until I updated it and then it wouldn't boot either. So I tried a new install of 15.10 guest VM again and sure enough it seems to be something in the latest updates that is the cause (as the 2 VMs I tried have different kernels - I need a later kernel for USB 3.0 capability).