# 14.04 (via VMWare Fusion) Hanging on Boot: "Stopping Log Initial Device Creation"

Tags: 14.04, boot, vmware

Installed some packages necessary for Chrome, as well as software updates recommended by the OS. On "sudo reboot" it is continously hanging up after several error messages:

```
*Stopping cold plug devices
*Stopping Restore Sound Card State
*Stopping Log Initial Device Creation
```

This is on a Mac OSX, running Mavericks (don't think that matters at all). I've tried bringing up a terminal during boot but I can't get anything to come up. Fusion immediately runs its typical stuff and then just completely freezes.

**EDIT:** was able to get into recovery mode and run dpkg. However, dpkg couldn't fix the packages since it couldn't make a connection with the ubuntu sever: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/

[pic of normal boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYtra.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS hangs on boot after latest dist-upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/738083/ubuntu-14-04-4-lts-hangs-on-boot-after-latest-dist-upgrade)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yes, this is related. thanks...