# Can't boot after upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, boot-repair, lts

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7559, which comes with ubuntu 14.04 LTS pre-installed.

After updating, the software update application gave an error indicating something wrong with my laptop with two options available: update or partial update for as many updates as possible. Running `sudo apt-get dist-uprade` fixed the issue.

Then I upgraded the Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS. Everything went well but until the installation rebooted and froze at the splash screen saying 'ubuntu....' .

I am new to Ubuntu, so could you please provide answers in a step-by-step manner?

Comment: So, does it hangs now on the splash screen? If it is, then if you try in Grub *(the menu on startup, might be disabled thoug, then just hold shift whilst PC is starting, the menu should appear)* to choose an old kernel version, does it fixes anything?

Comment: Doing a fresh install is faster than doing a full-upgrade. Just do a fresh install of xenial (16.04) and let your mind be free of old bugs!

Comment: This may help you http://askubuntu.com/a/738742/75060 I don't think it is a quite duplicate but rolling back the kernel is a solid suggestion to try.